# MVC Razor Form DropDownListFor objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list defined as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Properties, new SelectList(Model.Properties, "PropertyID", "PropertyName"))
```

When I submit to my form, the model has null in the `Properties` field. What am I doing wrong? Is my dropdown list incorrectly defined?

Comment: Paste your model definition.

Comment: You cant bind a `<select>` (or any other control) to a complex object. You need a separate value type property to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what type is your `Properties` object, but looking at the name I guess that is some kind of collection.

Usually DropDownList has only one value. So you should have something like that in your model:

```
public int PropertyId { get; set; }
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyId , new SelectList(Model.Properties, "PropertyID", "PropertyName"))
```

So when post occurs you can get selected item from this property.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProperty, new SelectList(Model.Properties, "PropertyID", "PropertyName"))
```

The selected value of your DropDownList would go into a different property i.e. model.SelectedProperty. This property should be of the same type as PropertyID (presumably int)